# Powershell script run as administrator from .exe compiled file

Tags: powershell, exe, windows-server, elevated-privileges, compiled

I am building a simple Powershell script for AD management.
I need to run as Admin this script from the .exe file (portable between Domain Controllers and/or Enviroments). Any suggest to make the exe file to request the Admin Privileges to the end-user (PopUp shield "can this program modify...")?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using ps2exe - https://github.com/MScholtes/PS2EXE
This can create an exe from a ps1 file and add things like required admin privilege's etc.

```
ps2exe .\source.ps1 .\target.exe -requireAdmin
```